# How to disable automatic running of "building flutter tool" and "pub upgrade"?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, flutter

So I decided to tinker around with Flutter.

Thus I downloaded the Flutter SDK (which contains the Dart SDK). I installed it (unpack, set bin to PATH).

Whenever I execute the `dart` command from the command line, it automatically triggers off building of the flutter tool as well as upgrading the pub tool, regardless of whether I want to or not. For example, as shown below:

[image]

(and mind you, when this happens, it also hogs a big chunk of the CPU % usage)

I wish to know how to disable this from happening. Either of these processes should be triggered only when I want them to be.

Comment: If you want to run plain Dart code, you should also download the vanilla Dart SDK and install that in a separate folder. Be sure to put the Dart SDK folder before the Flutter folder in the path.

Comment: Already tried that and it worked. But I'd rather not have two separate installations.

Moreover, even if I were developing Flutter, I'd rather not have pub upgrade and building flutter tool launch on their own.

Comment: building of flutter tool is one time requirement it should'nt be every time, and please install git and add flutter to path aswell as the dart sdk inside flutter to path